# Wordpress code completion dreamweaver

Tags: wordpress, dreamweaver

Does anyone know of an extension for Dreamweaver for WordPress code completion. If not for Dreamweaver could you suggest something else.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 and the Weave Into Wordpress extension which I found on the adobe exchange site. It provides code completion, syntax coloring, code hints and even usage instructions for most of the wordpress functions which is a nice bonus for me since i'm terrible at remembering function names.

Anyways you can get the extension [here](https://www.adobeexchange.com/store/products/433) if it takes your fancy.